# disable mouseover on flexigrid table header

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Im trying to disable de mouseover property in a dynamic grid generated via ajax with flexigrid with no luck, here is what i tried:

```
$('div.sundefined').on('mouseover', function(event) { 
    return false; 
});
```

sundefined is the class name of the table header. the weird thing is that if i fire it from firebug console. it works.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `.on()`, but you need to bind that to an element that exists at page load!

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div.sundefined', function(event) { 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: just tried doing that way, and it doesnt work not even with the firebug console. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
$('div.sundefined').off('mouseover');
```

or

```
$('div.sundefined').on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$('div.sundefined').on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

And indeed, if the div.sundefined is generated dynamically, you must follow the tymeJV's hint.

Comment: no luck yet. i've tried some similar implementations before with no luck